# Entity Framework Code First ReadOnly Entity

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Is there any way to mark an entity as read-only and not specify any key for it?

Comment: Code First and read only are kind of mutually exclusive.   Just out of curiosity why would you not want a primary key?

Comment: Enttity is mapped to a view and I don't want update/insert on it, an have no key on it either.

Comment: EF will not do updates on views by default.

Comment: @GertArnold, that is incorrect. You can update/insert views in EF.

Comment: Is this [information](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/5fb8d970-1131-4de7-a7fa-6cd1d7839e84/) outdated then? Could be, EF develops pretty fast.

Comment: Hmm. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716779.aspx) also has it. It is the _default_. Which does not mean that there are no work-arounds.

Comment: I think it is outdated. You can manipulate the edm file in database first approach to do this or just map to a view in code first. It will send a nice query to db engine and if your view is updatable it will work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a couple of things that you can do to enforce read-only in Code First. The first is to use `AsNoTracking()` when you query.

```
var readOnlyPeople = (from p in context.People
                        where p.LastName == "Smith"
                        select p).AsNoTracking();
```

This tells Code First to not track changes to these entities, so when you call `SaveChanges()` no changes made to these objects will be persisted.

The seccond thing you can do is set the state to `Unchanged` before calling `SaveChanges()`.

```
context.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
context.SaveChanges();
```

This tells Code First to ignore any changes that have been made to that entity.

As far as not having a key, all entities must have a key. This may not necessarily map to a primary key in the database, but it "must uniquely identify an entity type instance within an entity set".

Comment: Hi Brice, your suggestions are not ideal solutions for me (I would really prefer just marking that entity as read-only - which exists in NH) but I don't think what I want is possible with a neat solution in EF yet. As per "all entities must have a key", I kind a agree with you but sometimes you have to work with some views and they don't have any key and If I can mark entitiy as read-only why should I need a key.

Comment: Actually you can use an IReadOnlyEntity marker interface similar to the ICacheableEntity interface suggested here (There are blog posts describing this as well were I originally found the code, but I couldn't find them) http://stackoverflow.com/a/6593261/34474 There are some gotcha's with relations between them that you should consider (If any one is interested let me know) In the end we are doing what Brice suggested only in a more automated way.

Comment: If your view does not have a natural key, you can add one to help EntityFramework.

In the view definition:
SELECT
 NEWID() as [VirtualKey] ...

In the Entity's Map:
// Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.VirtualKey);

Answer (score 11):

Using code-first in EF6, I created some entities that reflect Views, which obviously shouldn't be modified or saved. To prevent the Entity from being changed, I used protected set properties:

```
public class TransplantCenterView
{
    public string TransplantsThisYear { get; protected set; }
}
```

Entity Framework is still able to set this property, but other developers can't accidentally do it without a compile-time error. This works great, but it seems the better solution would be to eliminate tracking completely.

---

Thanks to [reggaeguitar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45720709/482256), it appears there is an answer to this (please also vote his answer up if the following is helpful), which has allowed me to change my code from:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<TransplantCenterView> TransplantCenterViews { get; set; }
}
```

To:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    // appears the DbSet is still needed to make Set<Entity>() work
    protected DbSet<TransplantCenterView> _transplantCenterViews { get; set; }
    // this .AsNoTracking() disables tracking for our DbSet.
    public DbQuery<TransplantCenterView> TransplantCenterViews
    {
        get { return Set<TransplantCenterView>().AsNoTracking(); }
    }
}
```

I don't know of any pros and cons to this, but my existing code has continued working without any hitches, so seems a win.

Comment: See my answer for a way to disable tracking on the entity.

Comment: Devs _could_ still call MyContext.Set<TransplantCenterView>().DoAnyThing(), so I still prefer your `protected set` solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the entire entity to be read-only you can do this

```
/// Using a dbquery since this is readonly.
/// </summary>
public DbQuery<State> States
{
  get
  {
    // Don't track changes to query results
    return Set<State>().AsNoTracking();
 }
}
```

source http://www.adamtuliper.com/2012/12/read-only-entities-in-entity-framework.html

Comment: Changed DbSet to DbQuery.  Changed the getter to as described above.  Compiled. All good.  However, when I go to execute the page that loads data from the view I get a runtime error: "The entity type `MyEntityName` is not part of the model for the current context."  So, added `protected DbSet<MyEntityName> _hiddenMyEntitiesName {get; set;}` and then things worked.  It would be worthwhile to add the DbSet<> into your code above so people don't run into the same confusion...or if there's another way?  But thanks for putting me on the right path.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't get that error. I'm mapping to tables and not views, maybe that's the difference?

Comment: Hmm...so, you don't have a DbSet<State> property anywhere in your context, and it still works?  Odd...could also be a version issue.  I'm back on VS 2015 and EF6.

Comment: I don't have DbSet<State> only DbQuery<State> and my old LINQ queries work fine. I'm also on VS 2015 EF6

Comment: Rather than add the ***protected DbSet<MyEntityName> _hiddenMyEntitiesName {get; set;}*** to your context add ***modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntityName>();*** to the OnModelCreating method.

Comment: @JohnS Why? What's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

You can also make it read-only as a more "global" rule for a specific entity by type. Simply override the appropriate `SaveChanges*` method and set the entity's state if you see that EF is trying to add it during the save.

```cs
public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {
        if (entry.Entity.GetType() == typeof(<YOUR_TYPE_HERE>) && entry.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
}
```